# ASP.NET MVC calling stored procedure with error parameter not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC application trying to execute a stored procedure.

My stored procedure is like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_SelectFromQry] 
    @queryname NVARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT TBLNAME, TBLCOL, TBLCOLLABEL, POSITION
    FROM QRY
    WHERE QUERYNAME = @queryname
END
```

Inside my controller, I have written a code like this:

```
var result =  db.Database.SqlQuery<RESULT_FROM_QRY>("_SelectFromQry", new   SqlParameter("queryname","INVAVAIL")).ToList();
```

When the application reaches this line, I get a

> SqlCilent.SqlExcepction: procedure '_SelectFromQry' expects parameter '@queryname' which was not supplied.

I am not sure if I am calling the stored procedure correctly with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you need to include possible parameter name(s) inside query string like this:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<RESULT_FROM_QRY>("_SelectFromQry @queryname", 
             new SqlParameter("queryname", "INVAVAIL")).ToList();
```

Or optionally use `EXEC` prefix:

```
var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<RESULT_FROM_QRY>("EXEC _SelectFromQry @queryname", 
             new SqlParameter("queryname", "INVAVAIL")).ToList();
```

Since your stored procedure declares an input parameter without specifying default value of `NULL` (i.e. using required parameter instead of optional parameter), the parameter name must be supplied in order to execute it.

Reference:

[SQL Server stored procedure parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191517/sql-server-stored-procedure-parameters)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the issue is that you use "queryname" rather than "@queryname" in the SqlParameter constructor, i.e. this:

```
new SqlParameter("queryname","INVAVAIL")
```

should be this:

```
new SqlParameter("@queryname","INVAVAIL")
```

Comment: I modified accordingly to your way and still get the same exception... ...

Comment: In that case, I can only assume that there is an issue inside your `SqlQuery` method but you haven't shown us that code so I can only guess.